# Trying to put a variable into string so that the function imports a key, and then executes in a sheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

I'm working on a project where I'm trying to get a sheet to autoupdate with info from a new sheet every day. The new sheet will be dropped in the same folder and will be given the same name every day. However, I need to get the new sheet key every day to make the code run with the new sheet importing data.

I'm almost done, now I just need to get the string that was pushed to variable key into the importrange function on line 37. The tricky part about this is that the code imports it into the target sheet as a string where it then executes the actual import range function when it hits the sheet.

I need a way to get the variable key into that string such that it will still execute in the sheet OR dump the id that the variable is holding somewhere and then put it into that string automatically. Thanks so much in advance!

```
var counter = 0;

var files = [];
var key = (" ");

function searchFolder() {
 var folderId = '0B6wmHZ5c0fzfTjI1bFpKOHI3N3M'; // test folder
 // Log the name of every file in the folder.
 var filesN = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId).getFiles(); //log files in folder
 while (filesN.hasNext()) files.push(filesN.next().getName());
 while (filesN.hasNext()) 
keyID.push(filesN.next().getId());


}

function autoUpdate(){ //updates monthly from newly imported daily
 if (counter == 1){ //counter is made to be 1 when day is uploaded to monthly
var ss =     SpreadsheetApp.openById("1lH9Y12P2Q2OFndIJoAU48ePggXFc9WGcWjolZMcABoc");     //defines target spreadsheet ie monthly
 SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSpreadsheet(ss); //sets target spreadsheet as active
var range= ss.getRange("A1:A1"); //sets range in target. ONLY CHOOSE ONE   
range.activate;  // activates range
//HELP HERE PLEASE
range.setValue('=IMPORTRANGE("1hVv6ldHEaCCI_uptr0MpzAyP60x7on8YR_brWwWXTWo","sheet1!A1:167")'); //Puts in IMPORTRANGE into target as a STRING value (just words). Once it hits the sheet, then SHEETS executes IMPORTRANGE not SCRIPTS. In Source sheet, range is selected to import to target (ie A1:G6)
counter=(counter-1)
  }
 }

 function timeStamp(){
  if (files == "Daily") {
  counter= (counter+1)
  }
}

searchFolder();
timeStamp();
autoUpdate();
```

Comment: I just updated the line in question to be       range.setValue("=IMPORTRANGE"+"("+  key + ","+ "sheet1!A1:167"+")");

Now i get #REF error in the target google sheet telling me there's circular dependency. The importrange formula is missing where the sheet key would go, but the script in GAS executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you click on the #REF?  Because usually with an IMPORTRANGE function you have to "Allow Access" for it to pull data.  Until you do this it will display a #REF.  If you click on the cell a pop up should display with a button titled "Allow Access".

Once I did this on my test your original command, `range.setValue('=IMPORTRANGE("1hVv6ldHEaCCI_uptr0MpzAyP60x7on8YR_brWwWXTWo","sheet1!A1:167")')` worked.

Also to use a variable your command would look like this...
`range.setValue(('=IMPORTRANGE("'+key+'","sheet1!A1:167")'))`

**Update Based on Comments**

Change

```
  var files = [];
  var key = ("");
  var folderId = '0B6wmHZ5c0fzfTjI1bFpKOHI3N3M'; // test folder
     // Log the name of every file in the folder.
     var filesN = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId).getFiles(); //log files in folder
     while (filesN.hasNext()) files.push(filesN.next().getName());
     while (filesN.hasNext()) 
    keyID.push(filesN.next().getId());
```

To...

```
  var files = [];
  var key = [];
  var folderId = '0B6wmHZ5c0fzfTjI1bFpKOHI3N3M'; // test folder
  // Log the name of every file in the folder.
  var filesN = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId).getFiles(); //log files in folder
  while (filesN.hasNext()) {
    var file = filesN.next();
    key.push(file.getId())
    files.push(file.getName());
  }
  Logger.log(key)
```

This will create an array of file keys as well as an array of name...you could then loop through the key array to get each key individually and use the key variable in the command as shown previously.  I'm not really sure exactly what you are wanting to do so more specific help will need more information.

**UPDATE 8-14-2016**

This is what I meant regarding looping through the keys array.  I've tested and it works.

```
    function test() {
  var files = [];
  var keys = [];
  var folderId = '0B6wmHZ5c0fzfTjI1bFpKOHI3N3M'; // test folder
  // Log the name of every file in the folder.
  var filesN = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId).getFiles(); //log files in folder
  while (filesN.hasNext()) {
    var file = filesN.next();
    keys.push(file.getId())
    files.push(file.getName());
  }
  Logger.log(keys)

    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1lH9Y12P2Q2OFndIJoAU48ePggXFc9WGcWjolZMcABoc");     //defines target spreadsheet ie monthly
    SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSpreadsheet(ss); //sets target spreadsheet as active
    var s = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
    for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) { 
      var range = s.getRange(1,i+1); //sets range in target. ONLY CHOOSE ONE
      range.setValue('=IMPORTRANGE("'+keys[i]+'","sheet1!A1:167")')
    }
  autoUpdate(keys);
}
```

Comment: hi, sorry for the late response! i did allow access previously, the code worked before when i wasn't trying to import the key. i will try this though and get back to you!

Comment: hi mongoose, it still doesn't work. it gives me #N/A error in the code, telling me there's an import internal error. I changed the key.push fucntion to be keyID.push so it would push to the variable, but it didnt work. in the spreadsheet the import range function reads an empty " " where the key id i was trying to get is.

Comment: hi again @mongoose36 . I made this change to an array for the variables and it gave me an internal import error. I think this is because in order for the process to work, the parenthesis need to be there. I made it a string value originally because it's not apps that is executing the import range function, it's google sheets. Therefore I needed to make it a string so that once it hit sheets it would execute there. Hope this clarifies, I'm still looking for a solution to the problem.

Comment: Ok...I'm a little confused.  The key array is an array of strings.  If you loop through it each element should also be a string and should be able to be used in the command.  Perhaps if you could post your whole function so I can see exactly what is going on it would help.

Comment: Also what are the conditions by which you determine if the Id is the correct file or not.  You mentioned that a new file is placed into the folder with the same name.  How do you know which ID is new?

Comment: hey @mongoose36

here's the entirety of the code: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1-f1uLDQV3IgDrWbFnwROr8XsqTn-gE_LK2DWgjFk77M/edit?usp=sharing 

there's only one sheet populating the source folder at a time, this is done manually by our staff. so in the morning they take out the old file and put in the new one. all files are called daily so the code still works but the key id is different.

Comment: OH MY GOD IT WORKS YOU ARE INCREDIBLE YOU ARE A LIFESAVER WOW IT WORKS